# Python 2 vs Python 3 double underscore methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, compatibility, python-2.x

So in Python 3, I can use `object().__eq__`. I'm currently using it as a mappable function, equivalent to `lambda x: x is object()`.

I'm using it as a sentinel (As `None` would have a different meaning from no argument).

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>> object.__eq__
<slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
>>> object().__eq__
<method-wrapper '__eq__' of object object at 0x000002CC4E569120>
```

But in Python 2, this doesn't work:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>> object.__eq__
<method-wrapper '__eq__' of type object at 0x0000000054AA35C0>
>>> object().__eq__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__eq__'
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Why doesn't this function exist? And how can I emulate it (performantly with Python 2 compatibility)

```
$ python3 -m timeit "sentinel = object(); tests = [sentinel] * 100 + [None] * 100" "list(filter(sentinel.__eq__, tests))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.8 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "sentinel = object(); tests = [sentinel] * 100 + [None] * 100; exec('def is_sentinel(x): return sentinel is x', locals(), globals())" "list(filter(is_sentinel, tests))"
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.1 usec per loop
```

Comment: This is precisely why you shouldn't be using `__dunder__` methods like this. Use `import operator; operator.eq`

Comment: Or actually use `lambda thing: thing is sentinel`; equality isn't necessarily identity.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm using literally `s = object()`. For that, I think equality is defined as identity.

Comment: @Artyer but the semantics are different; identity makes it clearer to the reader what matters, in the same way that you should test `is None`.

Comment: @Artyer this is an interesting bit of arcana. I assume that this has to do with the distinction between old-style and new-style classes, which doesn't exist in Python 3. In Python 2, it seems, the `__eq__` method you see on `object` is inherited from `type`, whereas in Python 3, `object` has it's own `__eq__` method that isn't inherited. In any event, you should use the `operator` module for these things. In the Python 2 case, `object` instances don't have `__eq__` because `object.__eq__` belongs to the class object, not the instances. I.e., it is inherited form the metaclass `type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a function to test for equality against a fixed object, that's

```
from functools import partial
from operator import eq

equals_thing = partial(eq, thing) # instead of thing.__eq__
```

This will behave slightly differently from `thing.__eq__`, since it also gives the other argument a shot at providing the comparison, and it won't return `NotImplemented`.

If you want an identity test no matter what, use `operator.is_` instead of `operator.eq`:

```
from operator import is_

is_thing = partial(is_, thing)
```

If you actually wanted the Python 3 behavior of a raw `__eq__` call, `NotImplemented` and all, then depending on the type, you may have to reimplement it manually. For `object`, that'd be

```
lambda x: True if x is thing else NotImplemented
```

---

In Python 2, not every object defines an `__eq__`, and in fact, not every object defines any sort of equality comparison at all, even the old-style `__cmp__`. The identity comparison fallback for `==` happens outside of any object's method.

Comment: I didn't know about `operator.is_`. Thanks! I'll accept this when it lets me.